# What are good Regression Testing Tools?

Tags: automated-testing, regression-testing

Required Features:
- Open Source
- Can be used on Web Applications
- Can be used on GUI's
- Runs on Windows
- Can simulate mouse movement
- Can simulate keystrokes
- Record and playback capable

Comment: Do you asking for automation testing tool?

Comment: I'm not sure. My project manager only said "Regression Testing Tools".
Are regression testing tools and automation testing tools the same thing?

Comment: okay , but you should ask to manager about more clarification.

Comment: No they are not the same thing as you would know if you know the differnce between regression testing and automating testing

Comment: Here is a somewhat more complete and "official" list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_GUI_testing_tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are looking for Automation testing tool.

According to me you can use following tool for regression testing :

**1 - [Selenium WebDriver Detail](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)**

**2 - [Learn Selenium WebDriver](http://toolsqa.com)**

**3 - [Record and Playback using Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)**

**4 - [GUI Automation testing Tool](http://www.ranorex.com/)**

Using above tool you can perform all things which you have listed in question.

Also when we think about tool , it comes to automation tool. Other way is manual regression testing and that can be done manually and there is no tool use in that.

Selenium works only with Web applications. For window applications you can use **[QTP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/)**

Comment: Wow. Great answer. I really appreciate it. :)

But are there any more? Specifically for GUI Applications.

Comment: Yep , I have just updated answer.

Comment: Can you also suggest me some open source ones?

Comment: Other than ranorax tool , All are open source. So you can use freely.

Comment: But they only offer 30 day or 40 day trial versions. I am currently looking for a software that is completely free to use.

Comment: So you need UI automation testing tool which allow to use free?

Comment: Yes. If there are any you could suggest.

Comment: sure I will share once I got it.